# Drupal 7 User based access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working in Drupal 7. I am looking for access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes based on user rather than role, which is almost similar to [Nodeaccess](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) . Nodeaccess is in alpha stage, not recommended for production site.

Along with add/edit/view permission, two most important permissions like "**grant node permissions**" and "**grant own node permissions**" is must, almost similar to Google app sharing feature "Is owner/can view/can edit/can delete".

Could you please suggest some alternative module or hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://drupal.org/project/user_permissions this module should do the trick for you. Here you can give access to the user based on each user and not role.

Also check out http://drupal.org/project/content_access here besides role you can use the author id to set access.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
vishal

Comment: Hi Vishal, Thanks for answer. Unfortunately user_permission modules results in "Recoverable fatal error". Any idea about this error?

Comment: I have not used it myself. Try to submit an issue ticket on the module page. Also you can debug and see what is going wrong at the module level.